# Set default warehouse selector value of current user login with user in role on SOOrder screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

This is my coding for SiteID (Customized Existing Field)

```
 [PXDefault(typeof(Search<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupName,InnerJoin<PX.SM.Users, On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupMask,Equal<PX.SM.Users.groupMask>>,InnerJoin<INSite, On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupName,Equal<INSite.siteCD>>>>,Where<PX.SM.Users.pKID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>),PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

and when publish the project it got error:

```
 error CS0311: The type 'PX.Data.Where<PX.SM.Users.pKID,PX.Data.Equal<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userID>>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'OrderBy' in the generic type or method 'PX.Data.Search<Field,Where,OrderBy>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Data.Where<PX.SM.Users.pKID,PX.Data.Equal<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userID>>>' to 'PX.Data.IBqlOrderBy'.
 error CS0311: The type 'PX.Data.InnerJoin<PX.SM.Users,PX.Data.On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupMask,PX.Data.Equal<PX.SM.Users.groupMask>>,PX.Data.InnerJoin<PX.Objects.IN.INSite,PX.Data.On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupName,PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.IN.INSite.siteCD>>>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'Where' in the generic type or method 'PX.Data.Search<Field,Where,OrderBy>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Data.InnerJoin<PX.SM.Users,PX.Data.On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupMask,PX.Data.Equal<PX.SM.Users.groupMask>>,PX.Data.InnerJoin<PX.Objects.IN.INSite,PX.Data.On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupName,PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.IN.INSite.siteCD>>>>' to 'PX.Data.IBqlWhere'.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owcdY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have wrongly modified the PXDefault attribute.

If you want to set a default value using a BQL, you must be using the **Search** instead of PXSelect

**see the sample below**

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<SOOrderType.iNDocType, Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.orderType>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

Comment: After I changed it to Search it still got some errors!

Comment: @mei Search have different forms, what i wrote in the sample is just a search with where clause, you need join and all, so you might need to use different variants like search2, search3... need to check that

Comment: you should use Search2 i think. "Search2<Field, Join, Where>"

Comment: Anyways, can I ask you? If I want to set default of warehouse selector by current user login role, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Did you find the SQL query for that? which table and where from the information is needed?

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM dbo.RelationGroup a
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Users b ON a.GroupMask=b.GroupMask
  LEFT JOIN dbo.INSite c ON a.GroupName=c.SiteCD

Comment: where is the siteID there? if you can write the exact sql query may be i can try to help you to convert to corresponding BQL.

Comment: SiteID there it means Warehouse in Document Detail (SOOrder Screen). Above comment I reply to you is  my sql query.

Comment: Basically what you need to do is, you need to reconstruct your query as if INsite table comes first, for the current user info, you can use a where clause with AccessInfo.UserName to get the logged in user in your BQL.
your SQL queryis giving you expected result for the userID?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, anyways I want to select the default warehouse  WA for UserA so the user can see only his/her warehouse that assign in user role.

Comment: his/her warehouse that assign in user role? where is this option in acumatica ERP? May be you should ask this as a different question.

Comment: I assign it by Configuration->Role-Level Security->Warehouse Access->Create Group Name then assign user and warehouse. So On Screen SOOrder users can see the warehouse by assignment. But I want to set the default and user no need to select.

Comment: Or you can customize the Group screen or whatever you like by: add custom field, I'll call it UsrDefaultSiteID with SelectorAttribute with it. Then you can set the SiteID field in SOScreen with the select from your customized screen.

Comment: Ok, you have given the user permissions on warehouses. But still you dont have the information for the default warehouse. As @HDanh said, you should create such a field either in user screen or group screen(according to your req) then you query that value in your PXDefault attribute

Comment: @Hybridzz, you mean I should customize the new field like example UsrDefaultSiteID on Warehouse Access screen right?

Comment: There also ok. so did you create that?

Comment: @HDanh, should I customize new field on that screen like the picture that I show on my question?

Comment: @Hybridzz, yes I'm doing it.

Comment: @Mei, now i got your logic. You saved the siteCD as the groupname and you are trying to use that as the default warehouse for all users in that group. am i rite?

Comment: @Hybridzz, yes and set default value on screen SOOrder when the current user same as the user in Role(that assign in Warehouse Access).

Comment: my question is, are you saving the groupname as warehouse name? ie; SITECD? and is that your default warehouse for that group?

Comment: Sure that what I did.

Comment: [PXDefault(typeof(Search<INSite.siteID,
            InnerJoin<PX.SM.RelationGroup, On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupName, Equal<INSite.siteCD>>,
            InnerJoin<PX.SM.Users, On<PX.SM.RelationGroup.groupMask, Equal<PX.SM.Users.groupMask>>>>,
            Where<PX.SM.Users.pKID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ask you above.

Comment: I already told you to reconstruct your query in such a way that the insite table comes first. you should get the siteid for setting the value. is it working now?